# Asking a question in two places?

Tags: discussion, migration, cross-posting

If a question which is asked, has not received enough attention are we allowed to ask it in other exchange sites, stating that it is asked somewhere else too?

Comment: In some cases, the best plan is to *move* the question to the other site. In any case, wait a sufficiently long time before doing asking elsewhere —several days, at least.

Comment: How to move it? Just delete and ask again on the other site? You request that the question be migrated.

Comment: See [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10380/didnt-get-an-answer-should-i-cross-post-to-cross-validated) and [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/cross-posting-or-flag-for-migration).

Comment: You can also put a bounty on your question --- that might attract more attention. Or, you could start writing better questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you. Nice to see you here